# is it mandatory to configure both in my application?

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am using spring security for authentication. i have applicationContext-security.xml and custom login page(login.jsp). i have to implement **remember me** functionality. i have configured below two things. is it mandatory to configure both or one is enough? Please help me.

login.jsp:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="_spring_security_remember_me" />Remember Me
```

security.xml:

```
<remember-me key="_spring_security_remember_me"/>
```

are both above lines mandatory? also is **_spring_security_remember_me** convention is mandatory? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The checkbox in the JSP is used to let the user choose if a remember-me cookie should be set or not, allowing for transparent authentication later. Spring excepts such a request parameter to decide if the cookie must be set or not.

The key in the security.xml is used to generate a more difficult to guess hash to store in the cookie. You should put something only known by you. It's a secret key. See http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#remember-me